# Preventing nav buttons from collapsing in twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed header, however, whenever I go to shrink the screen, the buttons collapse so that each one gets their own row.

What do I need to do to adjust it so that the space between the 'Prev' and 'Next' button just shrinks, bringing the two closer together.

Please see the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/poppypoop/k4yp777s/

if you shrink the output window, the buttons eventually become enlarged and take up their own row. Anyway to prevent this?

here is my markup

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-default" role="navigation">             
            <div>
                <!--Left Align-->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="butt back" href="#"><span>Prev</span></a>                         
                    </li>
                </ul>


                <!--Right Align-->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a class="butt next" href="#"><span>Next</span></a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>                  
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: Don't use the navbar classes as they collapse and it's a pain to over-ride this behavior. Just use pull-right and pull-left and don't use surrounding ul and list, they are not necessary. http://jsfiddle.net/k4yp777s/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k4yp777s/1/

Comment: Christina, this is fantastic. Precisely what I was looking for. If you want to put it as an answer i'll gladly accept it